# "truetime-android" api returns wrong date and time sometimes?

Tags: android, datetime, time, current-time

I got the "truetime-android" api of version 1.7 from https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android.

It works fine. But sometimes it gives

1. wrong date-time

or

2. blank date-time?

Are these exception cases, device specific or android version specific or something else?

Comment: I think you should first share you code so we can rule out an incorrect use on your side.

Comment: I tried the exact code, explained by @Sultan Mahmud

Comment: Are you saying that you tried the exact code from Sultan Mahmoud’s answer and sometimes got a wrong date-time and sometimes go a blank date-time? That’s weird. I think that you should add this information in your question (use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55631323/edit) link).

Answer (score 3):

First, initialize the truetime with host and connection timeout like this:

```
public static void init(final Context context) {
    (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TrueTime.build().withNtpHost("time.google.com").withLoggingEnabled(false).withSharedPreferencesCache(context).withConnectionTimeout(31428).initialize();
            } catch (IOException var2) {
                var2.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    })).start();
}
```

Call this method for getting current time:

```
public static long getCurrentTrueTime() {
    Date trueDate = null;
    if (TrueTime.isInitialized()) {
        trueDate = TrueTime.now();
    }

    return trueDate != null ? trueDate.getTime() : System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Similarly, call this method for getting truetime:

```
public static Long getTrueTime() {
    Date trueDate = null;
    if (TrueTime.isInitialized()) {
        trueDate = TrueTime.now();
    }

    return trueDate != null ? trueDate.getTime() : null;
}
```

API Version:

```
api 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library:3.4'
```